# Is it possible to scrape data from this page?

Tags: python, html, data-extraction

I'm having issues with extracting table from this page, and I really need this data for my paper. I came up with this code, but it got stuck on second row.

```
browser.get('https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures/french-futures#!/2018/02/01')
table = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div')
html_table = html.fromstring(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
html_code = etree.tostring(html_table)
df = pd.read_html(html_code)[0]
df.drop(['Unnamed: 12', 'Unnamed: 13'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can always parse the table manually.

I prefer to use `BeautifulSoup` since I find it much easier to work with.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
```

Let's parse the first table, and get the column names:

```
table = soup.select("table.table-horizontal")[0]
columns = [i.get_text() for i in table.find_all("th")][:-2] ## We don't want the last 2 columns
```

Now, let's go through the table row by row:

```
rs = []
for r in table.find_all("tr"):
    ds = []
    for d in r.find_all("td"):
        ds.append(d.get_text().strip())
    rs.append(ds[:-2])
```

You can write the same code more concisely using list comprehensions:

```
rs = [[d.get_text().strip() for d in r.find_all("td")][:-2] for r in table.find_all("tr")]
```

Next, we filter `rs` to remove lists with `length != 12` (since we have 12 columns):

```
rs = [i for i in rs if len(i)==12]
```

Finally, we can put this into a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k:v for k, v in zip(columns, zip(*rs))})
```

You can follow a similar procedure for the second table. Hope this helps!